# Merging/migration should be reflected by the API

Tags: feature-request

Now that [we have a new merging/migration system that keeps records of all merges](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improved-question-merging/#comment-47662), I think that this information should be visible through the API:

- Questions that are merged into other questions should return some sort of a merge parameter for most requests
- Answers for the questions that are merged into other questions should return merge info as part of their revision history/timeline
- Questions that are merged into should return merge info as part of their revision history/timeline