# Why these questions do not have a title?

Tags: bug, status-deferred, questions, answers

Hitting the following `/questions` route:

http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/questions/74?pagesize=1&page=1

the endpoint returns this JSON data:

```
{
  "total": 1,
  "page": 1,
  "pagesize": 1,
  "questions": [
    {
      "answer_count": 0,
      "favorite_count": 0,
      "question_timeline_url": "/questions/74/timeline",
      "question_comments_url": "/questions/74/comments",
      "question_answers_url": "/questions/74/answers",
      "question_id": 74,
      "creation_date": 1217598122,
      "last_activity_date": 1217598122,
      "up_vote_count": 0,
      "down_vote_count": 0,
      "view_count": 0,
      "score": 0,
      "community_owned": false
    }
  ]
}
```

Another example with `question_id` 2733:

```
{
  "total": 1,
  "page": 1,
  "pagesize": 1,
  "questions": [
    {
      "answer_count": 0,
      "favorite_count": 0,
      "question_timeline_url": "/questions/2733/timeline",
      "question_comments_url": "/questions/2733/comments",
      "question_answers_url": "/questions/2733/answers",
      "question_id": 2733,
      "owner": {
        "user_id": 429,
        "user_type": "registered",
        "display_name": "Patrick",
        "reputation": 6466,
        "email_hash": "05ce4158a6d636a028bd108bf52cd492"
      },
      "creation_date": 1217964389,
      "last_edit_date": 1217964765,
      "last_activity_date": 1217964765,
      "up_vote_count": 8,
      "down_vote_count": 1,
      "view_count": 0,
      "score": 7,
      "community_owned": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Title parameter is missing; so what kind of question are these?
I found them because tipically I expect something like this for `question_id` not found:

```
{

     total: 0
     page: 1
     pagesize: 0
     questions: [ ]

}
```

**EDIT:**
Merging?
Related:
[Merging/migration should be reflected by the API](https://stackapps.com/questions/640/merging-migration-should-be-reflected-by-the-api)
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/50761/when-a-question-is-merged-redirect-original-question-url-to-new-one-automaticall

Comment: That's odd http://stackoverflow.com/questions/74 redirects to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34/unloading-a-bytearray-in-actionscript-3/74#74 (Note the anchor). Notice also, that the JSON doesn't have any tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because post id 74 is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34/unloading-a-bytearray-in-actionscript-3/74#74), not a question.

This was an undiscovered bug in the API back when we froze it, but enough [app]s depend on it that we haven't "fixed" it.

Naturally, answers have no titles or tags.

Comment: I'm discovering a lot of ids with the same behaviour on my log, is it useful to report them or you do not have problem to query them all from db?

Comment: @systempuntoout - every answer id (all ~3 million of them) will exhibit the same behavior.  Its basically [wont-fix] for v1, but will be resolved in a subsequent version.

Comment: so basically we get questions: [ ] just for question_id that does not have a question associated AND an answer with the same id?

Comment: @systempuntoout - questions and answers share an id sequence (note:  implementation detail, don't depend on that if possible), so there will never be an id that is valid for both an answer and an id.  You'll get [] back if the id hasn't been used (or was used, and the question/answer was deleted).