# How to get a post title for a given post ID, even if that post ID is an answer and not a question?

Tags: support, feature-request, documentation

I'm trying to beautify the reputation audit. If I want  to show the post title for a reputation change event, however, I have a problem -- I don't know if the post ID is relative to a question or an answer.

By poking around with the API a bit, it seems that the only way to get a result in my case is:

1. call `/answers/{id}`;
2. - [if I get a result](http://api.gaming.stackexchange.com/1.0/answers/303/) it's an answer, thus I should call [`/questions/{parent-id}/`](http://api.gaming.stackexchange.com/1.0/questions/300) for the title.
   - [If I don't get a result](http://api.gaming.stackexchange.com/1.0/answers/300/), it's  a question, thus I should call [`/questions/{id}`](http://api.gaming.stackexchange.com/1.0/questions/300) for the title.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Another non-write feature wanted...

Answer (score 5):

I believe that's a correct approach.

There's a way to optimize it saving one request but it's a little bit unsafe for [this bug](https://stackapps.com/questions/1800/why-these-questions-do-not-have-a-title):

1. call `/questions/{id}`;
2. - [If you get a result](http://api.gaming.stackexchange.com/1.0/questions/300/) with a *title* parameter it's a question
   - [If you get a result](http://api.gaming.stackexchange.com/1.0/questions/303/) without a *title* parameter it's an answer, thus you should call [/answers/{id}](http://api.gaming.stackexchange.com/1.0/answers/303)  for the *title*

**EDIT:**
I've just realized that your solution can be optimized easily just removing the `/questions/{parent-id}/`call;
you don't need it because `/answers/{id};` already has the `title` parameter inside the response.

Comment: Smart hack - given the [current roadmap](http://stackapps.com/questions/1909/roadmap-any-update) there are quite some requests to be saved still like so ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve this via the non optional "is_question" field of route [/revisions/{id}](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/help/method?method=revisions/%7Bid%7D):

```
   "is_question": {
        "description": "if the post is a question",
        "values": "boolean",
        "optional": false
      },
```

See for example the results for:

- [your question](http://api.stackapps.com/1.0/revisions/1926), which returns *true* accordingly
- [my answer](http://api.stackapps.com/1.0/revisions/1933), which returns *false*  accordingly

Comment: Uhm, */revisions* route does return the *parent-id* in case of answer. This would force badp to call */answers* anyway to get the *parent-id* and then */questions* to get the title.

Comment: Also, the call would return a lot of data I don't care about :)

Comment: @systempuntoout / @badp - both arguments are absolutely correct of course, I got carried away digging the API about a question/answer discriminator for a given post id and lost track of the mentioned use case, despite it being phrased elaborately (i.e. getting the post _title_ either way) - it has been (too) late for me apparently ;)

Comment: My comment above is partially correct. The */revision* route is not returning the *parent-id* field but it does not matter because */answers/{id};* returns the *title* costing just one request. So this is a valid solution too though with a bigger payload.